# Post Hoc test after lme

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, post-hoc, lme4-nlme

I am trying to run a Post Hoc test (`glht`) after a linear mixed model (`lme`) in `R`.
I was searching for a answer but couldn't find a helpful one.

Maybe I have some expectations to the model which my data doesn't support?

Here is my code:

```
library(nlme)
library(multcomp)

anova(mod <- lme(Yield~Crop, random=~1|ID, data=DFField, method="ML",na.action=na.omit))

            numDF denDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    53 948.9091  <.0001
Crop            2    15  14.7678   3e-04

glht(mod, linfct=mcp(Crop="Tukey"))
```

> Error in glht.matrix(model = list(modelStruct = list(reStruct = list(ID = -9.6584044661227)),  : 
>     ‘ncol(linfct)’ is not equal to ‘length(coef(model))’

DF:

```
ID  Crop    Yield
1   RMix    2294.36
1   RMix    4585.23
1   RMix    5979
1   RMix    6243.64
8   RMix    4396.24
8   RMix    5324.89
8   RMix    7266.89
27  MMix    7709.27
27  MMix    9342.2
27  MMix    5871.42
27  MMix    6244.97
35  MMix    9689.6
35  MMix    9449.34
35  MMix    7226.16
35  MMix    6090.7
2   RWet    6466.69
2   RWet    6301.73
2   RWet    6228.92
2   RWet    6093.93
9   RWet    7638.95
9   RWet    5047.91
9   RWet    6069.68
9   RWet    4827.53
21  MMix    6674.9
21  MMix    8106.99
21  MMix    6904.2
21  MMix    5708.12
22  MMix    6385.65
22  MMix    11056.43
22  MMix    5356.61
22  MMix    5631.58
3   RMix    3571.98
3   RMix    5293.26
3   RMix    5861.77
3   RMix    6483.02
11  RMix    4342.29
11  RMix    5470.5
11  RMix    5735.8
11  RMix    6083.33
23  RWet    6609.08
23  RWet    8229.66
23  RWet    6774.49
23  RWet    5917.72
33  RWet    7070.02
33  RWet    7309.89
33  RWet    5948.05
33  RWet    5784.07
4   MMix    15195.57
4   MMix    9117.13
4   MMix    5881.72
4   MMix    5431.84
14  MMix    11432.33
14  MMix    11052.94
14  MMix    5013.5
14  MMix    6682.77
25  RMix    2791.01
25  RMix    3825.83
25  RMix    6710.05
25  RMix    5285.8
26  RMix    2051.71
26  RMix    3115.92
26  RMix    6755.08
26  RMix    5568.8
15  RWet    7584.63
15  RWet    7213.5
15  RWet    5729.61
15  RWet    7140.97
16  RWet    6637.91
16  RWet    7791.15
16  RWet    5199.39
16  RWet    6801.6
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Your code runs without problems with the data provided.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Original I copied it out of a bigger DF with several columns, which I subsetted and where I removed NAs. Than I have an error inside my DF. If I look at my DF in R I don't find any NAs or obvious errors. I
It seems that subsetting outside of R solves the problem. Sometimes it is to easy and still cost several days.

Thanks a lot,

Emanuel